# Import users from 389 LDAP server to Azure Active directory

Tags: active-directory

I want to migrate the users from 389 LDAP server to Azure Active Directory (Azure AD).

I tried following options:

1. I exported users from 389 into LDIF file using Apache Directory Studio client. But on Azure AD, there is no option to import users from LDIF file.
2. There is option in Azure AD for Bulk User Creation using CSV. So I exported users from 389 into CSV file using Apache Directory Studio client. But the CSV FORMAT expected by Azure AD for importing users is totally different from the one I get using Apache DS client.

Azure documentation also suggests to use LDIFDE utility.
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/555636

But I am not sure where to run LDIFDE utility? Do I need to use Cloud shell(Power shell/Bash?)
Does anybody have idea how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

One of your servers may already have it installed. If so, it may be possible to copy two files to the system where you perform the import:

C:\WINDOWS\system32\ldifde.exe
C:\WINDOWS\system32\en-US\ldifde.exe.mui

(Use your locale if not en-US).

If you are performing the import using Windows 10 2018 H2 or later, ldifde may be installed by adding the Active Directory Domain Services and Lightweight Directory Services Tools capability.

```
DISM.exe /Online /Add-Capability /CapabilityName:Rsat.ActiveDirectory.DS-LDS.Tools~~~~0.0.1.0
```

If using a version of Windows 10 2018 H1 or earlier, there is a separate download for remote server administration tools:

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/remote/remote-server-administration-tools
https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=45520

LDIFDE documentation:

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2012-r2-and-2012/cc731033(v%3Dws.11)